# Python is not loading json

Tags: python

The code runs a script using a subprocess and returns json. If I print the json, it comes back fine, but when I try to load it with json.loads, there is this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
output, err = p.communicate()
outstring = str(output)
print(output) # This works
return json.loads(outstring) # This has the error
```

Edit: I tried `outstring.json()` but got this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'`

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question a few minutes ago?

Comment: The output is probably not JSON or has a trailing newline.

Comment: What does the `print(output)` look like? From the error, it seems like `output` is the empty string.

Comment: Attach the console output

Comment: Come to think of it, that would make the print just an empty line. What is `print(repr(output))`?

Comment: `str(output)` *does not* decode a `bytes` object to string. First off, the general contract of `str` is not to perform a type conversion so much as to produce a human-readable string representation; for `bytes` objects, that's the thing with quotation marks and a `b` prefix. Second, you **cannot** do this conversion *unless you know and specify the encoding*.

Answer (score 1):

You print `output` but then try to decode `outstring`. In fact, you got a `bytes` object back from stdout. When you made it into a string, you got the string represenation of the bytes object. So, if your json is `"foo"`, you tried to decode `"b'foo'"`. If your command is outputing utf-8, you can just pass it to `json.loads`. Otherwise you need to decode it first.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
output, err = p.communicate()
return json.loads(output)
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
output, err = p.communicate()
outstr = output.decode("utf-16") # or whatever encoding
return json.loads(outstr)
```